# DAX Index and Match?

Tags: function, dax, powerpivot

Good Afternoon,

What I am looking to do in Power Pivot is to bring a value dependant on two other columns within the same table.

What I did first: got the latest date for a name entered in the table. I now need to match an ID number based on teh name and the date.

For example:

```
ID   | Name    | Date        | Latest Date | ID Number
1    | John    | 1/1/2018    |  1/5/2018   |
2    | Kyle    | 1/15/2018   |  1/30/2018  |
3    | John    | 1/5/2018    |  1/5/2018   |
4    | Kyle    | 1/30/2018   |  1/30/2018  |
```

What I need is:

```
ID   | Name    | Date        | Latest Date | ID Number
1    | John    | 1/1/2018    |  1/5/2018   | 3
2    | Kyle    | 1/15/2018   |  1/30/2018  | 4
3    | John    | 1/5/2018    |  1/5/2018   | 3
4    | Kyle    | 1/30/2018   |  1/30/2018  | 4
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish script to accoplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent is the [LOOKUPVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) function.

This should work as a calculated column:

```
= LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[ID], Table1[Date], [Latest Date])
```

---

There are other ways to do this using filtering, but the above should be the most familiar.

Comment: Thanks, however I keep getting an error.  I think I forgot to mention that it is the ID based on the Name and the Latest Date.

Comment: This will break if there are multiple matching `ID` values for the values you are matching on. That is, if there isn't a single unique `ID` given a specific name and date. Can you double check that your matching always returns a single value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LOOKUPVALUE` if you will only ever have one ID number per Latest Date / Name.
Using this to return the ID which matches the Name and the Latest Date:

As a calculated column;

```
LOOKUPVALUE ( 
    Table1[ID], 
    Table1[Name], [Name], 
    Table1[Date], [Latest Date]
)
```

As a measure;

```
Latest ID:= 
VAR LookupName = 
    IF ( 
        HASONEVALUE ( Table1[Name] ),
        VALUES ( Table1[Name] ),
        BLANK ()
    )
VAR LookupDate = 
    IF ( 
        HASONEVALUE ( Table1[Latest Date] ),
        VALUES ( Table1[Latest Date] ),
        BLANK ()
    )
RETURN
    LOOKUPVALUE ( 
        Table1[ID],
        Table1[Name], LookupName,
        Table1[Date], LookupDate
    )
```

However, if you have more than one ID number with a matching name and date which matches the Latest Date, then this will return an error:

> A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

Instead, you could use:

```
Latest ID:= 
VAR LookupDate = 
    IF ( 
        HASONEVALUE ( Table1[Latest Date] ),
        VALUES ( Table1[Latest Date] ),
        BLANK ()
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        FIRSTNONBLANK ( Table1[ID] , 1),
        FILTER ( 
            ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Name] ),
            Table1[Date] = LookupDate
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but none of these solutions are working. It's in PowerPivot and all in the same table. I used the following DAX function (at the bottom). Perhaps my syntax is incorrect? I don't know how, though. I've watched countless youtube videos and I continue to get a #ERROR. Could it be that the latest date was entered based on another DAX function and the system cannot return the value?

Comment: =LOOKUPVALUE(table1[ID],table1[Name],[name],table1[date],[latestdate])

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Calculated ID Number =

VAR _slt =

    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Latest Date] )

RETURN

    LOOKUPVALUE ( 'Table'[ID], 'Table'[Date], _slt )
```

[the sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1slpEDn2v7ykRC902QfVvEoxOYuB4cuh4/view?usp=sharing)

[image: result]